# Meager topological spaces of uncountable size

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

Hello someone know examples of topological spaces of first category in themselves (meager in itself), that are not countable? Note that the Cantor set is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not meager in itself, because it is Baire.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [right order topology of $\Bbb R$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000042/properties/P000056) satisfies the requirement. The basis elements of this topology are the *right rays* $B_y=\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x>y\}$. Uncountability is obvious. In this topology, $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x<n\}$ (*left rays*). Notice the set $ \{x\in\Bbb R\mid x<n\}$ is nowhere dense by directly appealing to the definition.

Answer (score 4):

If $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a family of topological spaces, let $X = \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ be their coproduct (a.k.a. disjoint union).  Then $X$ is meager iff each $X_i$ is meager in itself (iff each $X_i$ is meager as a subset of $X$).  This is not hard to prove, using the observation that a subset $Y$ of $X$ is nowhere dense iff its intersection to each $X_i$ is nowhere dense.

It follows from this that for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, the coproduct $\coprod_{i \in \kappa} \mathbb{Q}$ of $\kappa$ copies of the rational numbers is a meager topological space of cardinality $\kappa$.  These spaces are all metrizable, as a coproduct of metrizable spaces is metrizable.